# Lowlevel format of SD card

Tags: windows-7, formatting, sd-card, bad-sectors

My SD card is defect. I can see that some pictures are not correctly saved (can't be opened) and I can't take new pictures. If I want to format it in Windows (chosing fast or really) it cancels the operation.

Can I lowlevel format my SD card to repair it? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to format 32GB memory card](http://superuser.com/questions/196888/unable-to-format-32gb-memory-card) also perhaps check out [What to do with a corrupted SD card: reformat it or trash it?](http://superuser.com/questions/62830/what-to-do-with-a-corrupted-sd-card-reformat-it-or-trash-it?rq=1)

Comment: Also see [How can I factory reset my microSD card](http://superuser.com/questions/531795/how-can-i-factory-reset-my-microsd-card).